# CSS Validation Issue: Not allowed div element in a tags

Tags: html, css, validation

I get this error after validating my HTML.

Line 18, Column 60: document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

```
 <a href="index.html"><div class="item" id="home"><br />
```

I think it says I'm not allowed to use DIVs in 'a' tags, but I have to use a layer if not a div here in order to get desired view. What can I use instead of div?

The error message includes these lines:

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "

" or "") inside an inline element (such as "", "", or "").

I get another error message for the line:

```
<a class="img" href="#"><li>Item 1</li></a>
```

I think I can't use `<li> </li>` tags inside `<a> </a>` tags, but in this case I have to, what do you suggest?

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS.

Comment: This is clearly not about CSS at all but about HTML.

Comment: The question is really about HTML validation errors, without sufficient information about context. It is impossible to say what markup should be done when the purpose and context have not been disclosed, just vague statement that “I have to” do something that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between a `<span>` and a `<div>` is that a `<span>` is a `display:inline;` element by default and `<div>` is a `display:block;` element by default.

You want to use an inline element within an inline element (`<a>`) because having a block element inside one doesn't make sense. An inline element continues with the 'flow' of a page while a block element breaks the flow (ie. goes to the next line).

Normally in these situations you can use a `<span>` without any problems.

**EDIT:** Making your `<a>` element have `display:block;` make also solve your problem.

**EDIT:** It is not actually valid HTML to have an `<li>` within an `<a>` tag, they must be within either a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Here are some options that will work fine, no extra CSS needed.

```
<a class="img" href="#">
    <span>Item 1</span>
</a>
```

Or

```
<div>
    <a class="img" href="#">Item 1</a>
</div>
```

Or

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="img" href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, but what about using <a> <li> Item </li> </a> ? It says 'li' is not allowed here.

Comment: Clever. OK I'm going to apply display:inline to li tags if I'm putting them in a tags. But how will I find out if I fixed the error while I can't upload the css and html files together in the validator?

Comment: You should put the `<a>` inside of the `<li>` instead.

Comment: @thgaskell placing the `<a>` in the `<li>` and no styles will produce different results so which ever works.

Comment: You can make a `<style>` tag in the head and throw your CSS in there so that they are validated as a whole.

Comment: @thgaskell then I'd have issues with the hover function, it would never highlight it unless I mouseover the link, but I want it to highlight when I'm over <li>. See?

Comment: I updated the answer with a few valid options without any extra CSS needed.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur You can still have it do that. Just put the hover style on the `<li>` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/PdDbE/1/

Answer (score 3):

Use a `<span>` instead, this is legal.

Comment: use `span` with `display:block` if needed.

Comment: No... that will generate the same error as currently. See my answer for why it doesn't make sense to have a block inside an inline.

Comment: Well I'm confused right now. Should I use <span> instead of <div> right there or not? And if I should use <span> should I make its display:block?

Comment: Oh I haven't uploaded my css file in the validator, it allows me to upload one file at once and I uploaded the html file. So, I'll get the same error as it won't see my 'display:block' in CSS. :/

Comment: Making a `<span>` `display:block;` is bad practice and you'll get the same validation error with both files :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to validate is changing your doctype to HTML5 as explained in this previous post:

[Valid HTML: ul, p, div inside 'a' element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495144/valid-html-ul-p-div-inside-a-element)

Hope this helps.